# Mysql server side paging , sorting

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

Hello I have one table in database which contains multiple columns , more than 20 and it contains many records about 2 millions

The table has one primary key : Col1 and it is also the index for my table 
, For some reasons , the data type for that column is varchar(200).

I am implementing server side paging ,sorting and later (filtering)

I face a problem in performance , here is my procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`master`@`%` PROCEDURE `spGetData`(
    IN  DisplayStart int ,
    IN  SortCol int ,
    IN  SortDir nvarchar(10),
    IN  Search  nvarchar(255)
)
BEGIN

        DECLARE FirstRec int;
        DECLARE LastRec int;

        SET FirstRec = DisplayStart;

            select 
               col1,col2,col3,col4,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11
               col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20
               col21,
                ( select count(*) from myTable) as filtered

            from myTable



order by
case When (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col1 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 0 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col1 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col2 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 1 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col2 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col3 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 2 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col3 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 3 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col4 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 3 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col4 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 4 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col5 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 4 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col5 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 5 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col6 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 5 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col6 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 6 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col7 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 6 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col7 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 7 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col8 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 7 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col8 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 8 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col9 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 8 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col9 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 9 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col10 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 9 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col10 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 10 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col11 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 10 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col11 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 11 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col12 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 11 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col12 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 12 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col13 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 12 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col13 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 13 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col14 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 13 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col14 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 14 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col15 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 14 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col15 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 15 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col16 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 15 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col16 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 16 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col17 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 16 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col17 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 17 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col18 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 17 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col18 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 18 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col19 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 18 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col19 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 19 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col20 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 19 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col20 end desc ,

case When (@SortCol = 20 and @SortDir = 'asc')  then col21 end asc ,
case When (@SortCol = 20 and @SortDir = 'desc') then col21 end desc ,


                limit FirstRec,10;

    END
```

The query is very slow and it gives a buffer size problem.
If i remove the order by clause , it becomes very fast.

So my questions are

1- How can i enhance this query and make sorting for millions of rows act fast?

2- Later i will apply filtering using a where clause for multiple columns , how can i avoid any performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

- The `ORDER BY` should be constructed (concat, prepare, execute, deallocate) instead of having that huge expression that cannot use any index.
- It is possible, but not realistic, to add `INDEX(col0), INDEX(col1), ...` so that the prepared statement will be fast in all 21 cases.  Pick the important ones and don't provide the rest to the end-user.
- [*Don't use OFFSET to paginate*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination); instead 'remember where you left off'.
- Where's the filtering?  It is likely to interfere with the tips I have already given you.
- `VARCHAR(200)` is usually unwise for the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Will the user be able to specify sorting on two columns?  Filtering on date ranges?  Other things?  (Please provide the real `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you want to get into more details.)
- Have you 'normalized' any columns?  That is, move large, frequently repeated, values into other tables.

Comment: hi @rick , The ORDER BY should be constructed (concat, prepare, execute, deallocate) instead of having that huge expression that cannot use any index. 

can you please clarify more ?

Comment: Search for "mysql procedure concat prepare", you will probably find lots of examples.